# Graphael Line chart show axis step incorrectly

Tags: graphael

I have created a line chart with graphael library. But it doesn't work right:
 - the x axis step doesn't show text.
 - the y axis step show incorrect mersuare.
Here í the code:

```
var paper = Raphael("chartNode","100%","100%");
        xAxis = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
        yData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
        options = {
            symbol: "circle",
            nostroke: false,
            smooth: false,
            shade: true,
            colors: ["#ffcc00","#ff0000"],
            axis: "0 0 1 1",
            axisxstep: xAxis.length - 1,
            axisystep: 10
        };


        var lines = paper.linechart(70,60,850,350,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],yData,options);

        lines.hoverColumn(function() {
            this.tags = paper.set();
            for ( var i = 0, ii = this.y.length; i < ii; i++) {
                tagDegree = i * 90 + 45;
                var nTag = paper.popup(this.x, this.y[i], ": "
                        + this.values[i], 'right', 5);
                this.tags.push(nTag.insertBefore(this).attr([ {
                    fill : "#8F6F4F"
                }, {
                    fill : "#ffffff"
                } ]));

            }
        }, function() {
            this.tags && this.tags.remove();
        });

        //set text for x axis
        $.each(lines.axis[0].text.items, function(index, label) {
            this.attr("text", xAxis[index]);
        });

        lines.symbols.attr({
            r:5
        });
```

And the result: [Result](http://www.flickr.com/photos/96516997@N02/8852488091/)

Please! help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is work fine. I think the error with your jquery ui lib.
Try re download the newest here: http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: Yes. This is my problem cause. Thank